# ArchUnit to stop changing the state of instance variables within Spring beans

Tags: archunit

I have Spring beans this way

```java
@Service
public class HotelsService {

    public List<Hotel> fetchAllHotels() {
        return dummyHotelsList();
    }
}
```

I should stop my developers from creating an instance variable within this bean and start changing the state within a method (see below snippet which i dont want to happen). Need to do this via archUnit. Didn't want to catch this during code review process

```java
@Service
public class HotelsService {
    private int someInteger;

    public List<Hotel> fetchAllHotels() {
        this.someInteger=1; // just for example
        return dummyHotelsList();
    }
}
```

I am ok to have instance variables and just read it. But don't want to write on it.

Any straightforward implementation in ArchUnit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to implement a custom (but straightforward... ) `ArchCondition`:

```java
ArchRule service_methods_should_not_set_service_fields =
    methods()
        .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(Service.class)
        .should(new ArchCondition<JavaMethod>("not set field of @Service class") {
            @Override
            public void check(JavaMethod method, ConditionEvents events) {
                method.getFieldAccesses().stream()
                    .filter(accessType(SET))
                    .filter(target(With.owner(annotatedWith(Service.class))))
                    .forEach(access -> events.add(violated(access, access.getDescription())));
            }
        })
        .because("beans should not have state");
```

using

```java
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaMethod;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.HasOwner.Predicates.With;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchCondition;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ConditionEvents;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaFieldAccess.AccessType.SET;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaFieldAccess.Predicates.accessType;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaFieldAccess.Predicates.target;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.annotatedWith;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.SimpleConditionEvent.violated;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.methods;
```

Your example fails with:

> Rule 'methods that are declared in classes that are annotated with @Service should not set field of @Service class, because beans should not have state' was violated (1 times):
> Method <HotelsService.fetchAllHotels()> sets field <HotelsService.someInteger> in (source code location)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem can be simplified at the level of requirements:
Do you really have to allow for non-constant fields in your services?

A (straightforward! ) rule to prevent those would be:

```java
ArchRule services_should_only_have_constant_fields =
    fields()
        .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(Service.class)
        .should().beStatic().andShould().beFinal()
        .because("beans should not have state");
```

Comment: Enforcing to make the variables final is the right thing to do. But we cannot afford that because of more usage of instance variables in our code base.. (fat code base) . So have to pick only the variables   Which are accessed in methods for changing state.. Reading is fine

Comment: I don't understand how the _usage of instance variables_ prevents making them `final`, or even `static final`.